# The $25$th digit of $100!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find The $25$th digit of $100!$.

**My attempt**:It is easy to know it has $24$ zeroes.Because:

$\lfloor {\frac{100}{5}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{100}{25}} \rfloor =24$

By getting the fist digits(after deleting all $5$ factors and $24$,$2$ factors)and multiplying them to each other we get the answer $4$ but I want an easier way.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial OR  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941235/how-to-find-the-last-non-zero-digit-of-n

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The second one doesn't have any nice answer but the first one was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the 24 zeros, divide them out, then

$$
x \equiv \frac{4^{10} 9^{10} 20!}{5^4} \equiv 6^2 {4!}^4 \pmod{10}
$$

Obviously $ x \not \equiv \{5, 0\} \pmod {10} $, due to $ 5 \nmid x $. Similarly, it contains factor $ 2 $, so it must be either $ 2, 4, 6, 8 $. At this point, you can simple evaluate it, and you will get $ 4 $.

Comment: Answer is 3  ( 100! is  93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000, calculator used www.careerbless.com/calculators/ScientificCalculator/ )

Comment: @Kiran: Not at all. Please don't downvote when the answer is correct. Read the number you posted again.

Comment: 25th digit is 3 only

Comment: @Kiran: We are obviously talking about the digit from the right, otherwise the question would be quite meaningless (also, hence the 24 zeros as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting this. I thought it is from left.

Comment: @M.Fischer Can we find 25th digit from right ?, What if there were 10 zeroes then can we still find the 25 digit from right ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha That's harder. The best way to do so would be to first find out the number of digits (i.e. reduce it to the form $ x = 10^n c $ with $ 0.1 < c < 1 $, and then find the $ n - 25 $ digit (divide $ 10^{n - 25} $ out under modulo 10)

Comment: @M.Fischer: how do you see $
x \equiv \dfrac{4^{10} 9^{10} 20!}{5^4}$ easily?

Comment: Prime factor $ 100! $ by grouping the divisors together. Let $ 100! = \prod_{n=1}^100 n $, then you can simply "partition" it into smaller products, $ (\prod_{n = 0, 5 \nmid 2n + 1}^{50} 2n + 1) (\prod_{n = 5, 5 | n}^{100} n)(\prod_{n = 1, 5 \nmid n, 2|n}^{100} n) $ (odd, even, products of fives, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

If we exclude the numbers that are divisible by 5, we see a cycle that repeats.

$4! = 24\\
9!/6!\equiv 24 \mod 100$

$100! = \frac {100!}{5^{20} 20!} (5^{20} 20!) = \frac {100!}{5^{20} 20!}\frac {20!}{5^4 4!} (4!)(5^{24})$

$(24^{25})(5^{24}) = (12^{25})(10^{24})(2)$

$12^{25} \equiv 12^5 \mod 100\equiv 32 \mod 100$

The last $2$ non-zero digits of 100! are $64.$